# Implement IWbemObjectSink interface in Rust

Tags: winapi, rust, interface, com, wmi

I'd like to be able to call ExecQueryAsync of SWbemServices in Rust, as in this example in C++ :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer-asynchronously

My problem is it needs an implementation of IWbemObjectSink, and none is available in winapi. The winapi crates provides [an interface definition in Rust](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/wbemcli/struct.IWbemObjectSink.html), but how am I supposed to "implement" it in Rust ?
I can write a struct that respects the interface, I can import the interface from the winapi crate, but how can I glue both together ?

I also made some experiments with com-rs crate, as it provides [an example to implement an interface with the com::class! macro](https://github.com/microsoft/com-rs)
But what I can do is create another IWbemObjectSink interface and implement it, not starting from the winapi::um::wbemcli:IWbemObjectSink and implement it...

Thanks for your insights

Comment: *"But what I can do is create another IWbemObjectSink interface and implement it"* - That's exactly what you want, though. It's your opportunity to provide a custom callback implementation, that you then pass into `ExecQueryAsync`. The latter calls into your `Indicate` implementation for each result it receives. The C++ sample code you linked to does exactly that (see the *QuerySink.h* and *QuerySink.cpp* files). So that is your solution, unless I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Hello @IInspectable thanks for your answer,
In my context, I "can't" create a new interface, even if it is exactly the same as the `winapi::um::wbemcli:IWbemObjectSink`, because Rust compiler wouldn't allow me to gives my interface to `ExecQueryAsync` instaed of a `winapi::um::wbemcli:IWbemObjectSink`. The maintainer of winapi crate advices me to look into `com-impl` crate instead of the more recent `com` crate, because the last one is not compatible with winapi. As soon as I have a working example, I post it here (for the moment, it compiles which is a great first step!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is trying to implement a COM interface of the [winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi) crate like IWbemObjectSink, for which WMI does not provide an implementation, here is a way to do so.

DON'T use the com-rs crate maintained by Microsoft as long as they don't add support for the winapi crate. Prefer the [com-impl](https://crates.io/crates/com-impl) crate, in combination with wio ComPtr (not necessary but handy).

```rust
use winapi::{
    um::wbemcli::{
        {IWbemClassObject,IWbemObjectSink, IWbemObjectSinkVtbl},
        WBEM_S_NO_ERROR,
    },
    shared::{
        ntdef::HRESULT,
        wtypes::BSTR,
    },
    ctypes::{
        c_long,
    },
};
use com_impl::{ComImpl, VTable, Refcount};
use wio::com::ComPtr;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(ComImpl)]
#[interfaces(IWbemObjectSink)]
pub struct QuerySink {
    vtbl: VTable<IWbemObjectSinkVtbl>,
    refcount: Refcount,
}

impl QuerySink {
    pub fn new() -> ComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> {
        let ptr = QuerySink::create_raw();
        let ptr = ptr as *mut IWbemObjectSink;
        unsafe { ComPtr::from_raw(ptr) }
    }
}

// AddRef and Release methods are provided by com_impl
#[com_impl::com_impl]
unsafe impl IWbemObjectSink for QuerySink2 {
    pub unsafe fn indicate(
        &self,
        _lObjectCount: c_long,
        _apObjArray: *mut *mut IWbemClassObject
    ) -> HRESULT {
        WBEM_S_NO_ERROR as i32
    }

    pub unsafe fn set_status(
        &self,
        _lFlags: c_long,
        _hResult: HRESULT,
        _strParam: BSTR,
        _pObjParam: *mut IWbemClassObject
    ) -> HRESULT {
        WBEM_S_NO_ERROR as i32
    }
}
```

Some other useful information:

**If you need to add members to your class (here `yolo` and `swag`), procede like this:**

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(ComImpl)]
#[interfaces(IWbemObjectSink)]
pub struct QuerySink2 {
    vtbl: VTable<IWbemObjectSinkVtbl>,
    refcount: Refcount,
    yolo: i32,
    swag: u8,
}

impl QuerySink2 {
    pub fn new(param1: i32, param2: u8) -> ComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> {
        let ptr = QuerySink2::create_raw(param1, param2);
        let ptr = ptr as *mut IWbemObjectSink;
        unsafe { ComPtr::from_raw(ptr) }
    }
}
```

**Method names are converted from snake_case to PascalCase by com-impl.**

That's why for my QuerySink I used `set_status` and `indicate` which are mapped to `SetStatus` and `Indicate`. com-impl provides a `#[com_name = "..."]` attribute if you want to do it your way. The best way to understand the details is to look at the comments in https://github.com/Connicpu/com-impl/blob/master/derive-com-impl/src/lib.rs